# Webdriver Manager for Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a problem the browser manager library does not work Webdriver Manager for Python. The following error appears, tell me how to fix it.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager


class MainPage:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(GeckoDriverManager().install())

    def __init__(self, link):
        self.link = link


    def connect(self):
        with self.driver as dr:
            dr.get(self.link)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    m = MainPage('https://ru.wikipedia.org/')
```

ValueError:

> Could not get version for Chrome with this command: reg query
> "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Google\Chrome\BLBeacon" /v version

Answer (score 0):

`GeckoDriverManager` - this should be for **FireFox**.

Why are you mixing things ?

```
 Chrome(GeckoDriverManager().install())
```

This is not right way.

Install **webdriver** **manager** like this :

```
pip3 install webdrivermanager
```

and instantiate chrome driver like this  :

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```

Comment: is the browserIndocker functionality exposed for the python library?